# Express-Handlebars Multiple Layouts

Tags: javascript, node.js, handlebars.js, express-handlebars

I am currently trying to use handlebars where I can reference multiple themes/layouts easily. My intention is for example, when rendering a new page I can choose which layout. Each layout links to a different set of JS/CSS files. For Example: I would be able to do:

```
router.get('/bootstrap', function (req, res){ 
   res.render('general', {layout: bootstrap, data: variables});   
});
                     ---or --
router.get('/semantic', function(req,res){
   res.render('general', {layout: semantic, data: variables});
```

I thought that this could be easily achieved by simply creating (bootstrap/semantic.hbs) templates like this in my **/views/layouts** directory and typing

```
res.render('general', {layout: 'bootstrap', data: variables});
```

However this doesnt seem to work

```
// bootstrap_layout.hbs

<html>
<head>
<link ref....to bootstrap css>
<body>
   {{{body}}}

<script src...to jquery>
<script src...to bootstrap js>
{{> Footer }}
</body>
<html>
```

My app.js file looks like this:

```
var express = require('express');
var exphbs  = require('express-handlebars');

var app = express();
var hbs = exphbs.create({
   layoutsDir: /views/layouts });

// Register `hbs.engine` with the Express app.
app.engine('handlebars', hbs.engine);
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');
```

The problem is when I try to do this, I cannot seem to load the layout/template when calling it in {layout: bootstrap} or {layout: semantic}. I run into errors where the layout cannot be found, vs other ENOENT errors. I also tried changing this:

```
Remove: var hbs = exphbs.create({
   layoutsDir: /views/layouts });
--------------------------------
Remove: hbs. engine, and replace with exphbs: 

app.engine('handlebars', exphbs({layoutDir: __dirname+'/views/layouts'}));
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');
```

I have had no luck in figuring out why I am running into so much difficulty calling a new layout. Does anyone have any advice on where I may be going wrong or if I am missing something essential?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Using single quote in the name of layout that you choose when you call render method:

```
res.render('general', {layout: 'bootstrap', data: variables});
```

Comment: right thats what I'm saying. I expect that to work and its not, thus why i'm posting here

Answer (score 0):

If you store your [bootstrap/semantic] layouts under views/layouts, it will work. So,

```
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');
app.set('views', './views');
```

and then

```
res.render('general', {layout: 'bootstrap', data: variables});
```

Answer (score 0):

One suggestion I have is that the extension on your layout files is incompatible with your configuration.

You have specified that your layouts have paths like `views/layouts/semantic.hbs`. However, I believe that [express-handlebars](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-handlebars) expects the extension ".handlebars" by default. (You can override this in your  `exphbs.create`, like `exphbs.create({ extname: '.hbs' })`)

In summary, please try using the ".handlebars" extension for your view files. The resultant paths would look like:

```
./views/general.handlebars
./views/layouts/bootstrap.handlebars
./views/layouts/semantic.handlebars
```

A basic example of the express code is:

```js
const express = require("express");
const exphbs = require("express-handlebars");
const path = require("path");

const app = express();
const port = 3000;

const hbs = exphbs.create({
  layoutsDir: path.join(__dirname, "/views/layouts"),
});

app.engine("handlebars", hbs.engine);
app.set("view engine", "handlebars");

const variables = {
  foo: "bar",
};

app.get("/bootstrap", function (req, res) {
  res.render("general", { layout: "bootstrap", data: variables });
});

app.get("/semantic", function (req, res) {
  res.render("general", { layout: "semantic", data: variables });
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}`);
});
```